# backup database mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I found this code

Run mysqldump using system() function

The system() function is used to execute an external program. Because MySQL already have built in tool for creating MySQL database backup (mysqldump) let's use it from our PHP script

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile";
system($command);

include 'closedb.php';
?>
```

From [HERE](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx). It is on how to backup database. I want to back up my database on button click or every month depending on the need so i search for a tutorial i found one but it does not clearly say much like

1. Where can i find the backup file if it was created.
2. Do i need to save it as `.sql` file or it is saved as sql already
3. If saved as `.sql` where can i find it

`UPDATE`

I used

```
    $mysqldump=exec('which mysqldump');
    $command = "$mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname > $dbname.sql";
    exec($command);
```

But i get a blank file and the size is `0 kb`

Answer (score 0):

I think writing a custom PHP script is overkill. If you need to backup your database monthly you can use cron, elsewhere use phpmyadmin.

Comment: hi can i ask what is cron i have not included any plugin in my project right now i am just using xampp as my server i would like to limit opening the xampp control panel so i wanted to have a button that will backup my database

Answer (score 0):

You wil find backup file in "./" (directory of actually running script)

Its saved like .sql witch is gziped

```
mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip
```

.SQL you can find in .gz file

```
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
```

You can use this script in cron for your monthly backup and in some "admin panel" by button for additional backups

Comment: hi can i ask what is cron i have not included any plugin in my project right now i am just using xampp as my server i would like to limit opening the xampp control panel so i wanted to have a button that will backup my database

Comment: Cron is job scheduler (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) you can set how often run some job.
And you can have button where you want. Only one think what you need is run this script after button click